# Read xlsx with openpyxl: formula evaluates to nothing/blank

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a spreadsheet where cell A1 contains the formula `=if(1,"","Strange")`. The value of this cell obviously equates to "": nothing/blank.

When I read cell A1 with openpyxl, the value returned is **0**, rather than an empty string. How can I distinguish between a "real" **0** and an empty string using openpyxl?

Thank you.

Marc.

Comment: I tried this using pandas with openpyxl as the engine and it worked fine.  `pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')`

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I was really looking to use just openpyxl, without pandas. However, I just created a minimal example and to my surprise the calculated blank cell is showing up as **None**, rather than **0**. This means I need to do some more digging in my main program to find out why it is different there.

Comment: Chris, I just found something interesting. It looks like it has to do with the vlookup formula that I am using. Consider the following. Cell D1:D4 has the numbers 1-4. Cell E1:E4 has the strings "Car", "Bike", "Train", <blank>. In A1 I have the formula `=VLOOKUP(4,D1:E4,2,0)`, which returns a blank cell. In A2 I have the formula `=IF(VLOOKUP(4,D1:E4,2,0)="","",VLOOKUP(4,D1:E4,2,0))`, which also returns a blank cell. When I read the values of A1 and A2 using openpyxl, it returns "0" for A1 and "None" for A2.